# Ubuntu Server init.d - testing if value is greater than 1

Tags: ubuntu, conditional-operator, init.d, minecraft

I am writing an init.d script and am looking to test if a returned value is greater than 1.  What would be the correct syntax for 'greater than'?

```
mc_status() {
        if ps ax | grep -ci 'CanaryMod.jar' > 0
        then
                echo "$SERVICE is running."
        else
                echo "$SERVICE is not running."
        fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my recollection init scripts are written in the sh shell. Many shell scripts use a pid file (usually found in /var/run) to check if a service is running. In your case a process as found in ps is used for validation.

The test you are performing is somewhat incorrect, as ps/grep are returning not a number but a set of characters or nothing. Try the following:

```
mc_status() {
        if [ ! -z "`ps ax | grep -ci 'CanaryMod.jar'`" ]; then
                echo "$SERVICE is running."
        else
                echo "$SERVICE is not running."
        fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you sosc, I ended up using the following based on your recommendations.  mc_status() {
  if [ "`ps ax | grep -ci 'CanaryMod.jar'`" -gt 1 ]
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is running."
  else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running."
  fi
}

Comment: my mistake I missed your "-c" parameter to grep... don't forget the tics around your command